# Edit pdf from existing Editable PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf

I am working on PHP, Codeignitor. I have one editable pdf. I want to fill the blank filed in the pdf, like First name, Last name, email. I am using FPDF and FPDI in php. First I include the fpdf and fpdi file.
    Create one function. My code is below. In that I have create object of FPDI.

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$path = base_url().'uploads/test.pdf';
$pdf->setSourceFile($path);
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $this->pdf->importPage(1);
//use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
//automaticallay and ajust the page size to the size of the imported page 
$this->pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
// now write some text above the imported page
$this->pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '13');
$this->pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
//set position in pdf document
$this->pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
//first parameter defines the line height
$this->pdf->Write(0, 'gift code');
//force the browser to download the output
$this->pdf->Output('gift_coupon_generated.pdf', 'D');
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

FPDI cannot handle PDF forms. The form fields get lost during the import process as described in the [FAQ](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-206):

> As FPDI does not modify a PDF document but imports it page by page into a structure which can be re-used with FPDF, all content outside a pages content stream, like form field annotations, get lost.

Anyhow you are still able to place text above the imported page. It's just a manual step to resolve the field coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the file first using ghost script. You can then import it using fpdi. Another step to your workflow but the quality is retained.

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-sColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged  \
-dAutoFilterColorImages=true \
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=true \
-dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
-dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
-dDownsampleColorImages=true \
-sOutputFile=document_flat.pdf document_original.pdf
```